# Distinct clause on one attribute and another attribute at random

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose i have this table:

```
A          B          

1          John Smith
1          Mr. John Smith
2          Tom Cruise
2          The actor Tom Cruise
3          Jim
```

I want to select distinct attributes A, but I don't care which of the records in B the query will return, because I know that, if two records they have the same attribute A, the attribute B will carry the same information, even it's not written in a standard way.

I want a table like this:

```
A          B          

1          John Smith
2          The actor Tom Cruise
3          Jim
```

What is the query I should use?
I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use aggregate function together with the `group by` clause, for example `min`:

```
select A
     , min(B) as B
from tbl
group by A
```